# How to target a class name in android WebView?

Tags: java, android, css, webview

I need to load WebView and need to modify the CSS based on div class, in my case I need to target to `innerClass`. For example I have this code in WebView:

```
<div class="myClass">
  <div class="innerClass">
     Some Text here.
  </div>
</div>
```

How I can set `innerClass` to be `display:none`?

Here's my code in `MainActivity.java`:

```
final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("https://xxxx.com");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript code like this:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // for alert
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello world')");
```

And you can achieve your goal by this:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('innerClass')[0].style.display = 'none'");
```

Here is full example:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private boolean isVisible = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // for alert, anyway.

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String htmlString = "<html><div class=\"myClass\">\n" +
                "myClass text here" +
                "  <div class=\"innerClass\">\n" +
                "     Some Text here.\n" +
                "  </div>\n" +
                "</div>" +
                "</html>";

        mWebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);

        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello world')");
    }

    public void toggle(View view) {
        if (isVisible) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var d = document.getElementsByClassName('innerClass')[0]; d.setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\");");
        } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var d = document.getElementsByClassName('innerClass')[0]; d.setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:visible;\");");
        }
        isVisible = !isVisible;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="runJavascript"
        android:text="Click"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am sorry to have confused you. I edited code, and this code was tested.